# TextView doesn't appear the whole text

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin

what can i do to make the whole text in textView appear?

```
 <TextView
            android:text="رَضيـتُ بِاللهِ رَبَّـاً وَبِالإسْلامِ ديـناً وَبِمُحَـمَّدٍ صلى الله عليه وسلم نَبِيّـاً."
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="76.0dp"
            android:id="@+id/textVieww48"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:paddingTop="30px"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:lines="2"
            android:minEms="2"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:singleLine="false" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting the max number of lines to 2, also forcing the textview to have 2 lines, a fixed height and you're enabling the ellipsize...

Try without those options:

```
<TextView
            android:text="رَضيـتُ بِاللهِ رَبَّـاً وَبِالإسْلامِ ديـناً وَبِمُحَـمَّدٍ صلى الله عليه وسلم نَبِيّـاً."
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textVieww48"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:paddingTop="30px"/>
```

Comment: it's worked thank you so much!